# Draw circle onClick at mouse location with D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to work with D3 for a simple web app.  I'm new to D3 (and web applications in general), but the current goal is to draw a circle wherever I click inside a single `Div`.  I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-basic-shapes-and-d3js) to draw my circle.  However, after adding this code in, I'm not getting a black circle to appear.  I posted the code below... is there something I'm missing? (BTW, the console log is working perfectly)

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/topo_creator.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="../javascript/graph.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="view_graph" id="graph" onclick="graphClicked(event);">

    </div>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
function graphClicked(event) {
var x = event.pageX;
var y = event.pageY;

var offsetX = document.getElementById('graph').offsetLeft;
var offsetY = document.getElementById('graph').offsetTop;

var divWidth = document.getElementById('graph').clientWidth;
var divHeight = document.getElementById('graph').clientHeight;

var svg = d3.select('graph').append('svg')
            .attr('width', divWidth)
            .attr('height', divHeight);

var circle = svg.append('circle')
                .attr('cx', (x - offsetX))
                .attr('cy', (y - offsetY))
                .attr('r', 20);

console.log('clicked: ' + (x - offsetX) + ' , ' + (y - offsetY));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `#` to indicate this is an html id.

> ```
> var svg = d3.select('#graph').append('svg')
>             .attr('width', divWidth)
>             .attr('height', divHeight);
> ```

See here (http://codepen.io/f7o/pen/zBZBWY)

Comment: That was it!  I'm kinda new to html so when do I need to use the `#`?  Also, as a follow-up question, I'm trying to have the circles only appear in the 'div' that I created, but after inserting the first properly, they are placed below the 'div'... is there any reason for this?